# How to temporarily override a member of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

There are times when it's necessary to override a dictionary member that might already exist, execute arbitrary code (such as a callback, which could fail) then set the value back to it's previous state (which includes not being present).

Keeping a copy of the dictionary isn't an option since this dictionary might have other members modified by the callback (which I want to keep).

How should a dictionary item be overridden temporarily?

Comment: There is no built in support for such a use-case, you would have to write out the logic of doing this yourself, which would involve keeping track of the original state, and making sure that state is reverted to once you finish with the code.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga right, this seems like something a re-usable context manager might support, or even a mocking library.

Comment: Well, I don't think there is anything in the standard library, although I'm not super familiar with `unittest.mock`. But yeah, creating your own context-manager for this would seem to be relatively straight-forward

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you're correct as-ever; `unittest.mock` indeed provides a dict-like patching method (see [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66269610/4541045)), which is also a context manager .. but practically it's best to only summon up `unittest` in tests and write such an implementation yourself elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very straight-forward implementation:

```
import contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def temp_item(dictionary, key, value):
    empty = object()
    original = dictionary.get(key, empty)
    dictionary[key] = value
    try:
        yield dictionary
    finally:
        if original is empty:
            dictionary.pop(key, None)
        else:
            dictionary[key] = original
```

This can be used as follows:

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
with temp_item(d, 'c', '3') as d:
    d['d'] = 4
    d['a'] = 10
    print(d['c'])
print(d)
```

Which outputs:

```
3
{'a': 10, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: I'd rely on directly indexing and catching `KeyError` to determine if the key is absent, as an arbitrary dict _could_ have `object`, `None`, `uuid4()`, `"big string sentinel"`, etc. in it (however unlikely)

Comment: @ti7 it will *never* have that object I'm using as a sentinel, though.

Comment: Ah - I see; that's subtle and clever - the docs specify it's [always _new_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object) and so will have a different id against your  `is` compare!

Comment: @ti7 it's actually a relatively common idiom, you even see it in the standard library.

Comment: @KellyBundy whoops, yeah, logic error, fixed. EDIT, using a `dictionary.pop(key, default)` approach makes it cleaner

Answer (score 1):

`unittest.mock` provides [`patch.dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.dict)

It can patch not only dictionaries, but objects that behave like them and also clear out the mock with or without mocking its contents

However, it's probably best to only rely on `unittest` in a test context

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

class TestWhatever(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_dictionary_mocking(self):
        with patch.dict("os.environ", {"RUNNING_AS_DOCKER": "true"}): 
            self.assertTrue(detect_docker())
        with patch.dict("os.environ", clear=True):
            self.assertFalse(detect_docker())
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done inline using a try/finally block.

```py
# Set to any object you know the dictionary won't use as a value.
sentinel = object()
value_orig = mydict.get(key, sentinel)
mydict[key] = value_new
try:
    run_callback()
finally:
    if value_orig is sentinel:
        # Use pop in case the callback added this key.
        mydict.pop(key, None)
    else:
        mydict[key] = value_orig
```

Wrapped into a context manager that takes a dictionary as an argument (instead of a single `key: value` pair, for added flexibility):

```py
class DictOverride:
    __slots__ = ("dict_base", "items_override", "values_orig")
    _sentinel = object()

    def __init__(self, dict_base, dict_override):
        sentinel = self._sentinel
        self.items_override = tuple(dict_override.items())
        self.values_orig = [
            dict_base.get(key, sentinel)
            for key, _ in self.items_override
        ]
        self.dict_base = dict_base

    def __enter__(self):
        dict_base = self.dict_base
        for key, value in self.items_override:
            dict_base[key] = value

    def __exit__(self, _type, _value, _traceback):
        sentinel = self._sentinel
        dict_base = self.dict_base
        for (key, value), value_orig in zip(
                self.items_override,
                self.values_orig,
        ):
            if value_orig is sentinel:
                dict_base.pop(key)
            else:
                dict_base[key] = value_orig
```

```py
# COntext manager test case
dct_test = {"eggs": "soft", "coconut": "hard"}
print("Original:", dct_test)
with DictOverride(dct_test, {"eggs": "hard"}):
    print("Override:", dct_test)
print("Original:", dct_test, "(again)")
```

Which outputs:

```
Original: {'eggs': 'soft', 'coconut': 'hard'}
Override: {'eggs': 'hard', 'coconut': 'hard'}
Original: {'eggs': 'soft', 'coconut': 'hard'} (again)
```